# How to add an app icon to a RubyMotion OS X app?

Tags: macos, rubymotion

I am creating an OS X app with RubyMotion. I want to add an app icon. I copied my `stopwatch.png` file to the resources directory and specified the filename in the `Rakefile`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/osx'

begin
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.require
rescue LoadError
end

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  app.name = 'Timetracker'
  app.icon = 'stopwatch.png'
end
```

When I run `rake` it does not apply my icon. I even ran `rake build` and the `.app` created does not use my icon. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify a direct image it needs to be in the format of a `.icns` file.

SOURCE: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubymotion/TxkA9IjRRM4

Convert here: http://iconverticons.com/online/

You may need to run `rake clean` for your icon change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like [iConvert Icons](http://iconverticons.com/online/) generated a valid `.icns` file, but for some reason, when I run `rake` or `rake build`, RubyMotion still does not apply the icon.

Comment: Finally got it to work. Had to run `rake clean` for the change to take effect.

Comment: Would be great if this was updated to state it only supports .icns and not single images too... http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/project-management/